# Context menu single click Android

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-contextmenu

I'm new to the Android development. I was trying to add a context menu to my app. I understood that by default it requires long click on the button to open the context menu. But I need to make it to appear on the single click. I tried all the other solutions here in stackoverflow but none of them are really helping me.

I have posted my code below. kindly let me know what are the modifications to be done to make it working.

```
public class ThirdActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third_layout);
        confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
        registerForContextMenu(confirmButton);
}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");
}


public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      if (item.getTitle() == "Action 1") {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
just :

public class ThirdActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third_layout);
        confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
    confirmButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            confirmButton .performLongClick();
        }
    });
        registerForContextMenu(confirmButton); 
} 

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");
} 


public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      if (item.getTitle() == "Action 1") {
        //do something 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Or tray to register a hide btn as ContextMenuBtn.And when click a visible btn,the hide btn performLongClick.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
 confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.showContextMenu();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure since which Android version, the behaviour changed when view.showContextMenu() is called. I'm on Android 13 (API 33) and it shows a full width dialog in middle of the screen instead of the usual context menu which appears at the clicked position. I even tried calling view.performLongClick() and again it shows the new UI style, hinting that someone at Google really wants to reserve the usual context menu only for actual long click event!

I almost gave up, until I found that showContextMenu() has an overloaded method showContextMenu(x, y) which accepts x y coordinates, and seems like it will create the usual context menu spawning from the x and y coordinates specified.

As for how to obtain the x and y coordinates of the clicked position, this is what I used:

```
private var lastTouchedPositionX: Float = 0.0f
private var lastTouchedPositionY: Float = 0.0f
itemView.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
    when (motionEvent.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            lastTouchedPositionX = motionEvent.x
            lastTouchedPositionY = motionEvent.y
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            if (motionEvent.x == lastTouchedPositionX && motionEvent.y == lastTouchedPositionY) {
                // item is clicked
                itemView.showContextMenu(lastTouchedPositionX, lastTouchedPositionY)
            }
            lastTouchedPositionX = 0.0f
            lastTouchedPositionY = 0.0f
        }
    }
    true
}
```

I used setOnTouchListener because setOnClickListener doesn't return the x and y coordinates, while setOnTouchListener does, and I assume if ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP both happened at the same coordinate that means a click event has happened, and so we call showContextMenu(x, y)

Seems to work fine on Android 13, haven't tested older versions though.